# Welcome Email 1.9 disable sending this email

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I have tried the other answers but have been unsuccessful. I am fairly new to PHP, XML, OOP, and Magento, sorry about that...

I would like to **disable** the "**Welcome** new customer **email**" that is sent when a **new client** has created a new account, that is the **only scenario** I wish to disable.

can you please tell me:

- The name and address of the file or files.
- Location of the snippet or snippets to change in the file 
  (line number or surrounding code)
- What is happening when I change it.
- What is it I am changing ( function , property , object, ...)
- One great Magento newbi help tip. ;-)

Is the  `sendNewAccountEmail()` being triggered from both a Global and Local variable? almost like a fail safe?

Thank you so much for your time, professional help and advice.
dond223

Answer (score 0):

1. The base file is in : `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`.
2. The function is : `sendNewAccountEmail();`
3. If you want to update this function, you have to rewrite this model : `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`in local codepool `app/code/local`, you can find many tutorial to how to rewrite Magento Model.

   Maybe you ask yourself the question, why we rewrite the model instead to update it directly in the original folder ? So because it's forbidden to update the native Magento files `app/code/core/...` and this for many reasons, I can give you one reason quickly : If you update directly the native file, and one day if you install a patch of upgrade the Magento version or some magento updates, if that file is updated, you'll lose your updates+ errors.
4. The template of welcome customer email is in: `app/locale/languagecode_ISO/template/email/account_new.html`
5. If you want to disable sending Emails : comment these two lines in that function `sendNewAccountEmail()` :

   ```
   //$this->_sendEmailTemplate($types[$type], self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
           //array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl), $storeId);
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Prince. Upon reading your "forbidden" warning I chose to accept that I should just let the email annoyance be. I also really appreciate your professional help and easy to understand explanations. You ROCK! Thank you again !!!

Comment: You're welcome ;) If the answer helped you, you can accept it.